# Need to have Date format as dd.mm.yyyy for column using excel vba

Tags: excel, date

I am new to Excel vba.. Currently working on creating macro for internal purpose where i manipulating the Date in that.

Currently i am Entering the date in Text Box and further then converted to date in required format using known function "cell.numberformat="dd.mm.yyyy"".

However still date is displayed as per local setting say "11/22/2018" in the formula bar instead of displaying "22.11.2018"

problem we further import the excel to SAP, there it assumes date format from formula bar and hence its not recognized in our SAP system.

Could you please let us know is there an any way to have date format same in column as well as in Formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

The date format dd.mm.yyyy is not recognised as a date by Excel. You would have therefore to change the contents of the cell to a string representation of the date. This would mess up any formulas that were doing any calculations on those dates (such as number of days btweeen dates etc). If you want to go down this route then this macro will convert all selected cells into text with the desired formula:

```
 Sub ConvertDates
 Dim r as range
 For each r in selection
      r.formula = format(r.value,"dd.mm.yyyy")
 next r
 end sub
```